# No response from Fetch API in React useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use the fetch API in React useEffect hook to make a get request but I am not able to Print my response as expected. I am only getting an empty array as the response.

**This is my code.**

```
function App() {
  const [eventData,setEventData] = useState([]);
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async()=>{
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch('https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events');
      const {events} = await res.json();
      setEventData(events);
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchData();
    console.log(eventData)
  },[])
return (
    <div> 
      {{!loading ? <Map eventData={eventData}/> : <Loader/>}}
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default App;
```

**this is my output**

[image]

But if write the *console.log* statement after the useEffect hook I am getting the expected output. I don't understand why it's behaving in this way. It would be much appreciated if someone can explain the reason for this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's because the state is updated asynchronously and fetch is also async.

Comment: yeah now I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous so you can't see the updated value in the function where you set a new value, where you `console.log(eventData)`, you need to do `console.log(events)` to see what you get from the response

And, by the way, I recommend you to set loading at true by default because you do your request when the component mounts `const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);`, then you can remove the `setLoading(true);` in the function

```
function App() {
  const [eventData,setEventData] = useState([]);
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async()=>{
      const res = await fetch('https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events');
      const {events} = await res.json();
    console.log(events)
      setEventData(events);
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchData();
  },[])
return (
    <div> 
      {!loading ? <Map eventData={eventData}/> : <Loader/>}
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default App;
```

Comment: Now I understand it. And thanks for the tip. cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to get the value of eventData before the state is updated move console.log(eventData) outside useEffect like so

```js
function App() {
  const [eventData,setEventData] = useState([]);
  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async()=>{
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch('https://eonet.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/api/v2.1/events');
      const {events} = await res.json();
      setEventData(events);
      setLoading(false);
    }

    fetchData();
  
  },[])

  console.log(eventData) //Here

return (
    <div> 
      {{!loading ? <Map eventData={eventData}/> : <Loader/>}}
    </div>
  );
}
  
export default App;
```

Comment: Yeah I think that is because setState() is asynchronous. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`

```
function RecipesList() {

  

  //use effect to

  useEffect(() => {

    const getRecipesList = async () => {

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/recipe/allrecipes", {

        method: "GET",

      });

      const json = await response.json();

      if (response.ok) {

        setData(json);

        const allCategories = [

          "all",

          ...new Set(data.map((item) => item.category)),

        ];

        setCategories(allCategories);

      }

      

    };

    getRecipesList();

    //get all categories from data

  }, []);

  };

 

}

Want to populate categories array base on data array

Data array is populated from databse



`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).