# React hook is not calling API after first load sometimes not at all

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a very simple website that I'm using based off React, hosted on Firebase.  On localhost and on my hosted site, I have ONE page that loads an API. Whenever I load that API, that page stops working usually after the first attempt, sometimes it doesn't work at all until I change the return statement to empty and back again. I was using class components and the error never occurred BUT I was unable to access a lot of the information in data.

The problem: My hook is not setting the state, data.

the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'volumeInfo' of null

the question: How do I get my hook to call every time on page load?

cross reference error: [No response from Fetch API in React useEffect hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373481/no-response-from-fetch-api-in-react-useeffect-hook) I looked at this post, hopefully for guidance, but it's still not loading.

the code:

```js
import '../App.css';
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import React, { useState, Component, useEffect } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';


const Milestone1 = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const callAPI = async () => {
            try {
                fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/Wfan6L9RGgYC")
                    .then((res) => res.json())
                    .then((data) => setData(data));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }

        };
        callAPI();
    }, []);
    console.log(data);



    return <>{(
        <div className="school">
            <header className="App-header">
                
            </header>
            <center>
                <div className="navigation">
                    <Navigation />
                </div>
                <body className="App-body">

                    <body className="App-body">
                        <h2>Milestone 1</h2>
                        <h5>Title: {data && data.volumeInfo.title}</h5>
                        <img src={data.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="image" />

                        <h5>Authors: {data && data.volumeInfo.authors} Publish info: {data && data.volumeInfo.publisher} {data && data.volumeInfo.publishedDate} Country: {data && data.saleInfo.country}</h5>

                        <h5>Rating: {data && data.volumeInfo.averageRating}</h5>
                    </body>
                    <NavLink to="/Milestone1part2">Milestone 1 part two</NavLink><br></br>
                </body>
            </center>
         
        </div>
    )}</>;
}




export default Milestone1;
```

my other hook that's dumbed down:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/Wfan6L9RGgYC")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => setData(data));
    }, []);
```

I've read similar posts, and usually they have a button in the page or something that can recall the API, but 1) it's not an interactive page 2) the whole page is not loading.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the data starts as null value, and then you try to render something like `null.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail` in here `<img src={data.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="image" />`

Try to add a loading component to handle the null data and to avoid this code `{data && data.something}`.

```
  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loadding...</div>;
  }
```

Example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-firefly-ej0yk?file=/src/App.js:0-1276

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Milestone1 = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const callAPI = async () => {
      try {
        fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/Wfan6L9RGgYC")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => setData(data));
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    callAPI();
  }, []);
  console.log(data);

  if (!data) {
    return <div>Loadding...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="school">
      <header className="App-header"></header>
      <center>
        <div className="navigation"></div>
        <body className="App-body">
          <body className="App-body">
            <h2>Milestone 1</h2>
            <h5>Title: {data.volumeInfo.title}</h5>
            <img src={data.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail} alt="image" />

            <h5>
              Authors: {data.volumeInfo.authors} Publish info:{" "}
              {data.volumeInfo.publisher} {data.volumeInfo.publishedDate}{" "}
              Country: {data.saleInfo.country}
            </h5>

            <h5>Rating: {data.volumeInfo.averageRating}</h5>
          </body>
        </body>
      </center>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Milestone1;
```